# 'ansible_date_time' is undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

Trying to register an ec2 instance in AWS with Ansible's ec2_ami module, and using current date/time as version (we'll end up making a lot of AMIs in the future).

This is what I have:

```
- name: Create new AMI
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
  tasks:
    - include_vars: ami_vars.yml
    - debug: var=ansible_date_time
    - name: Register ec2 instance as AMI
      ec2_ami: aws_access_key={{ ec2_access_key }}
               aws_secret_key={{ ec2_secret_key }}
               instance_id={{ temp_instance.instance_ids[0] }}
               region={{ region }}
               wait=yes
               name={{ ami_name }}
      with_items: temp_instance
      register: new_ami
```

From ami_vars.yml:

```
ami_version: "{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}"
ami_name: ami_test_{{ ami_version }}
```

When I run the full playbook, I get this error message:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! ERROR! ERROR! 'ansible_date_time' is undefined"}
```

However, when run the debug command separately, from a separate playbook, it works fine:

```
- name: Test date-time lookup
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - include_vars: ami_vars.yml
    - debug: msg="ami version is {{ ami_version }}"
    - debug: msg="ami name is {{ ami_name }}"
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ami version is 2016-02-05T19:32:24Z"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "ami name is ami_test_2016-02-05T19:32:24Z"
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Remove this:

```
  gather_facts: false
```

`ansible_date_time` is part of the facts and you are not gathering it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Now getting a different error but that's pretty much just formatting issues lol.

Comment: what if you need gather_facts ?

Comment: @AbhilashMishra If you cannot run `gather_facts` on the host being managed (it may not even be created yet, or added to AD or DNS, whatever), then you can run the `setup` module with `delegate_to: localhost` (or use `localaction`), and use `hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time`.

Answer (score 2):

```
> cat tasks/test.yml 
---
- hosts: node
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset:
          - min
    - name: q
      debug: var=ansible_date_time.epoch
```

and run

```
 > ansible-playbook -i conf/share_var.conf tasks/test.yml  --private-key=/root/.ssh/id_rsa -u ${USER} -b --become-method=sudo 

PLAY [node] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xxxx.94.182]
ok: [xxxx.94.183]
ok: [xxxx.94.181]

TASK [q] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xxxx.94.181] => {
    "ansible_date_time.epoch": "1636712223"
}
ok: [xxxx.94.182] => {
    "ansible_date_time.epoch": "1636712223"
}
ok: [xxxx.94.183] => {
    "ansible_date_time.epoch": "1636712223"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
xxxx.94.181               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
xxxx.94.182               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
xxxx.94.183               : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```